# Nearest thing to allowing entry of text or date in list

Tags: 2010, list, validation

I have a list which collects the dates that systems were lasted tested on. Ideally therefore, I would like it to be a date field. This way, SP uses built-in functionality to validate the entries.

However, some of these systems have never been tested. It is hard to tell these systems, which have blank dates, to systems were no one has yet entered the information (which also have blank dates). Therefore, I'd like it if I could have some way for users to indicate "No Test Date", or some similar text.

Does anybody know how to achieve this? I considered using regex to check for either, but it's not allowed in column validation. I also considered using a default value of "Not updated", so any blanks would clearly mean the fields had never been tested, but had been updated. However, I get syntax errors when trying this.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably just set it up as a Test Date column, then in the form the next field would be a check box (Yes/No field) indicating if the machine has never been tested.

The form could then do some things like if a date is entered, deselect the check box automatically.